# Select check boxes as user wish Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, checkbox, webdriver

I want to click on checkboxes by getting user options. I have tried some code segments.How can I do it..It is better if it could get the list of check box labels and select options according to those options by the user.Can anyone please help.
Selenium 3.4
Chrome driver
I am new to test automation.I am using selenium web driver with java.
I have to do the automation by doing self learning.please help me
Thank you

Comment: Sure we will help you. Can you post the DOM and the code you have tried

Comment: This is the code I have tried recently.It is for select every boxes.It is not work.But I want to select boxes buy getting user inputs.I couldn't to find solution for it===code====List<WebElement> cboxes=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#editcom > div > div.addoff_div50text.right > div:nth-child(3) > div > div > div:nth-child(2)"));
  System.out.println(Integer.toString(cboxes.size()));
  for(WebElement ele:cboxes){
   ele.click();
  }====I have no DOM of the web page..I want to print labels of the check boxes and then user can input their options.Thank you very much for helping

Comment: not able to see the code. Did you missed something?

Comment: List<WebElement> cboxes=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#editcom > div > div.addoff_div50text.right > div:nth-child(3) > div > div > div:nth-child(2)"));
  System.out.println(Integer.toString(cboxes.size()));
  for(WebElement ele:cboxes){
   ele.click();
  }                                                                                                                                   There are 20 ceck boxes

Comment: website URL please?

Comment: This is the URL : https://offerhut.lk/               ******** If you can give me a example code for scenario which I have given,I can try it out with my scenario..If there are any mistake then I can inform you and ask.thank you

Comment: I am not able to see any check boxes on that page

Comment: Have to register and select I am a seller and then when doing edit company I have to select check boxes.In the home page there are no any check boxes.Can you help me suggesting me an example code for given scenario by me.It's a great help.Thank you very much for helping

Comment: Check with this xpath... //*[@class='divleft50'][i]/input If you pass 1 instead of i it will select the first element Automobile and if you pass 20 it will click the last element Books and stationery. Check and if it works for you i will paste this as answer

Comment: for(int i=1;i<=20;i++){
   
   WebElement ele=driver.findElement(By.xpath(" //*[@class='divleft50']["+i+"]/input"));
   //String value=ele.get(i).getText();
   //System.out.println(value);
   String categoryName=ele.getAttribute("value");
   System.out.println("Categories are : "+categoryName);
   //ele.click(); 
  }        ******I have tried out with this code segment it doesn't display the element name.It displays the umbers 1 to 20.How should I get element name

Comment: It wont print element name..... But it will click correctly. Workaround is get the input from user and pass the number accordingly in the xpath

Comment: Yeah.It clicked.but it doesn't click all the element.Can you suggest me a way to print the check box labels and click customized elements as user wish.Can you please help me.I tried in different ways.but I have no idea.

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='divleft50'][1]")).getText(); what the output you are getting dude?

Comment: Also, the xpath that i have provided before... I am able to click all those 20 check boxes

Comment: for(int i=1;i<=20;i++){
   
   
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='divleft50']["+i+"]"))‌​.getText();
   
  } ===========I executed this and got the outputs as Element : 1 Element : 2 ... up to Element : 20

Comment: This is not straightly doable. Lets say if the user input is "automobile" pass 1 as value in the xpath. We can use a map to do this.. getText is not working for this particular scenario.

Comment: <div class="divleft50" style="min-width: 174px;">
<input id="2_ck" value="2" name="cat[]" type="checkbox"/>
 Baby & Toddler
</div>

Comment: All the 20 elements are in div tags like this.I tried to get the value such as Baby & Toddler etc.But I do not how to retrieve it.But I tried out by getting id..It prints all the id of each element.Then how can I get this label name..I have used this code segment.It clicks all the element.But the thing I want is not happen===================>>    for(int i=1;i<=20;i++){
   WebElement ele=driver.findElement(By.xpath(" //*[@class='divleft50']["+i+"]/input"));
   System.out.println("Categories: "+ele.getAttribute("id"));
   ele.click();
  }

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the site and tried using getText(), but this approach is not working. We can use Map as a work around to key the number and checkbox values. Below codes might give you some idea.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    //Add all the values as key value pait in Map
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("Automobile".toLowerCase(), 1);
    map.put("Baby & Toddler".toLowerCase(), 2);
    // Similary add for all 20 elements

    String toClick = "Automobile";
    WebElement element = findCheckBox(map,toClick,driver);

    //This clicks on the Automobile check box


}

private static WebElement findCheckBox(HashMap<String, Integer> map, String toClick, WebDriver driver) 
{
    int number = map.get(toClick.toLowerCase());
    return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='divleft50']["+number+"]/input"));

}
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot..I will try it out and say you whether it worked or not.I didn't understand how that happen.So,I will take some time and try.Thank you very much

Comment: It is not working for me.Then what should I do.Please help me

Comment: can you give me the code that you have tried.. will try to help you

Comment: Ok.But I cannot paste the whole code in this text field.It says it is too long